# frp connection reset by peer

Tags: ssl, https, fiddler

I met a problem, could any one tell my how to solve or why?
I often run a fiddler in my computer to capture http/https packets, but it only can gets local network packets. Recently I try to use frp (a reverse proxy), I deploy it's frps in a cloud server, and frpc in my computer. Then I run fiddler, it can works (in my phone, I config a wifi proxy use frp's config). But I find some websites couldn't access, example [www.v2ex.com](http://www.v2ex.com) (But many others can, example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)). In my browser it says ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

So, I use curl to test it, here is the result:
it's seems a handshake error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRvaf.png)

If I don't use the proxy, it's OK. Or I direct access [www.v2ex.com](http://www.v2ex.com) through local fiddler, it's also OK.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pdaY.png)

And access google, it's OK:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vGFP.png)

And Here's my frps's config:

```ini
bindPort = 10020
```

my frpc's config:

```ini
serverAddr = "my cloud server IP"
serverPort = 10020

[[proxies]]
name = "test-tcp"
type = "tcp"
localIP = "127.0.0.1"
localPort = 8888
remotePort = 10021
```